# Using AsyncTask to load images into a custom adapter

Tags: android, android-asynctask, lazy-loading, adapter

Although there are many tutorials out there, I've found it really difficult to implement an AsyncTask to load images from URI's (obtained from a content provider) into a custom adapter.

I get the basic gist, which is to have a class containing an AsyncTask, do the bitmap creation in the 'doInBackground', and then set the ImageView in the onPostExecute.

The problem for me, being new to android & programming, is that I don't know how to pass in my Uri's to the AsyncTask for each item, how to create the bitmap, and how to return it to the adapter.

I've only gotten this far with the actual AsyncTask class (ImageLoader):

```
package another.music.player;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {

    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... uri) {

        // Create bitmap from passed in Uri here

        return bitmap;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null && imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        }
    }
}
```

And my custom adapter looks like this:

```
package another.music.player;

import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns;
import android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.AudioColumns;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.CursorAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

class AlbumAdapter extends CursorAdapter {

    public AlbumAdapter(Context context, Cursor c, int flags) {
        super(context, c, flags);
    }

    private static Uri currentSongUri;

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        ImageView albumArt = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.albumArt);
        TextView text1 = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.artistTitle);
        TextView text2 = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.albumTitle);
        TextView text3 = (TextView) view.getTag(R.id.totalSongs);

        albumArt.setImageBitmap(null);

        text1.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ARTIST)));
        text2.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AudioColumns.ALBUM)));
        text3.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AlbumColumns.NUMBER_OF_SONGS)));

        String currentAlbumId = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(BaseColumns._ID));

        Integer currentAlbumIdLong = Integer.parseInt(currentAlbumId);
        Uri artworkUri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");
        currentSongUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(artworkUri,
                currentAlbumIdLong);

        //Run ImageLoader AsyncTask here, and somehow retrieve the ImageView & set it.

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.albumitem, null);
        view.setTag(R.id.albumArt, view.findViewById(R.id.albumArt));
        view.setTag(R.id.artistTitle, view.findViewById(R.id.artistTitle));
        view.setTag(R.id.albumTitle, view.findViewById(R.id.albumTitle));
        view.setTag(R.id.totalSongs, view.findViewById(R.id.totalSongs));

        return view;
    }

}
```

I would be very grateful if somebody could show me how to proceed with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you develop this app called Shuttle Music Player ?

Comment: Hi, yes I did. I'm more than familiar with AsyncTasks now!

Comment: You should be using AsyncTask outside of the Adapter and then re-populating the results once it has completed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to pass your `AsyncTask` the view so that it can update it when it completes:

```
//Run ImageLoader AsyncTask here, and let it set the ImageView when it is done.
new ImageLoader().execute(view, uri);
```

And modify `AsyncTask` so that it can handle mixed parameter types:

```
public class ImageLoader extends AsyncTask<Object, String, Bitmap> {

    private View view;
    private Bitmap bitmap = null;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... parameters) {

        // Get the passed arguments here
        view = (View) parameters[0];
        String uri = (String)parameters[1];

        // Create bitmap from passed in Uri here
        // ...
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null && view != null) {
            ImageView albumArt = (ImageView) view.getTag(R.id.albumArt);
            albumArt.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
```

I haven't tested this code but it should give you an idea.

Comment: thanks for that. I will give it a go. The only other thing is that I'm also having trouble creating the bitmap. I'm not sure how to create a bitmap from a uri, because I can't seem to use decodeInputStream without a context..

Comment: then you can also pass context as argument: `new ImageLoader().execute(view, uri, context);` and also `Context context = (Context)parameters[2];
`

Comment: So you are suggesting that a new thread should be spooled each time the CursorAdapter executes bindView()? This will run a thread for each row in the cursor which will drain the device battery and potentially destroy system services if the max pool size is reached

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing setImage in **AsyncTask**? You can do it in a **thread**. I don't think in this condition AsyncTask would be good. Better you do it in different thread.

Comment: `AsyncTask` runs on different thread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: I don't necessarily need to do it in the way I've shown. The bitmap could just be returned to the adapter and then the imageview would be set. I'm open to suggestions. From all the stuff I've read though, I do believe I should be using AsyncTask in some manner.

Comment: I know AsyncTask runs in a different thread. I preffered not to do this task in AsyncTask. Anyways if its fulfilling the requirement you can do it in this.

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was voted down, @Debarati is pointing out that using AsyncTask in this context is an over kill. You require no thread pooling or cancellation so why not just use Thread?

Comment: From what I've read, `AsyncTask` allows you to communicate easily with the UI, `Thread` does not.